# How do I solve this git issue?

Tags: git, github

I used git a month ago for contributing in a project. There I made a branch of my name and added files in the same branch. After that I uninstalled git. Now again I installed git and made a new branch with the same name. But this branch is not showing commits I made earlier. My question is how do I recover my old branch on whom I was working. Please help and I will be very thankful.

Comment: Did you push the branch to the repository or still have the original folder where you made the branch? If not, you unfortunately can't recover it.

Comment: Do you have your old project directory still? It should contain the branch and commits. Creating a new branch of same name in a new repository does not automatically link it to branches of same name in other directories.

Comment: My issue solved I just needed to open git bash on that folder where it was cloned before thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If before you deleted git you were checked out to that branch then, if you still have the folder you may see the files there. If this is not the case then unless you pushed the changes to a remote repository like on GitHub then I don't think there's a way to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

**You gave very few details about your problem.**
I think you're talking about a project in an online repository.
If you pushed your commits, then it should be all in the online repo, so with a `git clone https://....` you download all the packets and with something like `git log --all` you can see all the commits/branches.
If you haven't pushed the changes, but the file you changed is still in your local repository (with its `.git` folder), the branch must be present here.
You must provide more details if it's not what you asked!